# Create Vuforia Targets programmatically

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, vuforia

I'm trying to explore the Vuforia API, but the documentation has only explanations of what the methods/classes do. If I want to learn how can I scan objects myself and add them to a dataset for example, what should I know first? And are there any simple tutorials to start with (Android preferably, I don't want to work with Unity).

Comment: What is the connection between your title and the question itself? Is what you need is a tutorial for how to manually scan an object and create the dataset (no programming involved)?

Comment: @yakobom There is always a connection between the title and the content. I don't want to use Vuforia's application, I want to create something like it. So yeah, I need programming involved, most tutorials tend to go with the easy Vuforia Object Scanner-then-import-to-unity way.

Comment: Sorry, but what you wrote was by far less clear than you think...Of course Vuforia's documentation only explain what and not how - it is not open source and they do not reveal much about how they do stuff.  So you want to create your own Vuforia-like SDK, including the object scanning? Pure Android and image processing?

Comment: @yakobom Vuforia has a documentation of their API, like any other API, they provide you with information regarding their classes and methods, but the hierarchy is not very clear, and of course, every tutorial I found, either uses their own app to scan objects, or find an already made model. I'm not looking to do those, I've already done it and it works fine, what I need now is something like what you said, but using Vuforia API.

Comment: @yakobom https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/reference/java/index.html here is a reference to their Java API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible with Vuforia - there is no published SDK for doing what the Object Scanner does (and the Object Scanner itself is not even available for other platforms but Android), so you cannot make one of your own.

The only currently available way to use Vuforia with scanned objects is to use their app, and feed the scanned OD file into the Target Manager

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you think capturing an image and sending it through HTTP to the Target Manager (using Vuforia Web Services) is something doable? I can't seem to find a solution to capture an image when Vuforia launches its GLView with a camera feed

Comment: I did not try it, you should try it out if you can bare the 'latency' in your product flow - I guess each new target will cause a delay of quite a few seconds. Anyway, this is only for 'regular' 2D targets, of course. For getting the image, you can use Vuforia's 'getFrame'. Also, I don't know if i t helps, but if you are not familiar with User Defined Targets, check it out, perhaps it can help you a bit